# how to get value without decimalformat from the edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

i have `EditText` and on `addTextChangedListener` i am converting the value to `DecimalFormat`.

for decimalformat i have written following code:

```
   df = new DecimalFormat("#,###.##");
        df.setDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown(true);
        dfnd = new DecimalFormat("#,###");
        this.et = et;
        hasFractionalPart = false;
```

So now if i am type `34987` then it will convert into `34,987`.

Now on button click i want the value from that `EditText` without the `DecimalFormat`.

```
I want the output same as 34987.
```

how to remove that `decimalformat` while we are getting the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal(editText.geText().toString().replaceAll(",", ""));
```

or you could use the parse method of DecimalFormat

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html